# undefined method total_pages in will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I have got an error in `will_paginate gem`

In the controller

```
@like_posts = current_user.likes.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10).map(&:post)
```

When I use in the view

```
<%= will_paginate(@like_posts) %><br/>
<%= page_entries_info(@like_posts) %><br/>
```

I got this error

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0xaae2dec>

24: <%= will_paginate(@like_posts) %><br/>
25: <%= page_entries_info(@like_posts) %><br/>
```

and if i change make this in the controller

```
   @like_posts = current_user.likes.order("created_at DESC").map(&:post).page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

i have this error

```
 undefined method `page' for#<Array:0xabcd34c>
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem of me that i want the pagination to work on static array and it is very dangerous so will_paginate refuse it and like to work with the query from the database

here is the trouble shooting of will_paginate

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Troubleshooting

i solve it by make 2 objects

```
   @likes = current_user.likes.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
   @like_posts = @likes.map(&:post)
```

in view

```
  <%= will_paginate @likes %><br/>
  <%= page_entries_info @likes %><br/>
```

use @likes for pagination and @like_posts to iterate on posts

Answer (score 0):

That may be solved by adding `require 'will_paginate/array'` at the top of your `application_controller.rb`:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```